# Find the column name which has the maximum value for each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max, argmax

I have a DataFrame like this one:

```
Communications and Search   Business    General Lifestyle
0   0.745763    0.050847    0.118644    0.084746
0   0.333333    0.000000    0.583333    0.083333
0   0.617021    0.042553    0.297872    0.042553
0   0.435897    0.000000    0.410256    0.153846
0   0.358974    0.076923    0.410256    0.153846
```

I want to create a new column  comprised of the column labels of each row’s maximum value. The desired output is like this:

```
Communications and Search   Business    General Lifestyle  Max
0   0.745763    0.050847    0.118644    0.084746           Communications 
0   0.333333    0.000000    0.583333    0.083333           Business  
0   0.617021    0.042553    0.297872    0.042553           Communications 
0   0.435897    0.000000    0.410256    0.153846           Communications 
0   0.358974    0.076923    0.410256    0.153846           Business
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73903067/19123103) handles cases where the max value may not be unique (works if they are unique as well).

Answer (score 301, accepted):

You can use [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) with `axis=1` to find the column with the greatest value on each row:

```
>>> df.idxmax(axis=1)
0    Communications
1          Business
2    Communications
3    Communications
4          Business
dtype: object
```

To create the new column 'Max', use `df['Max'] = df.idxmax(axis=1)`.

To find the *row* index at which the maximum value occurs in each column, use `df.idxmax()` (or equivalently `df.idxmax(axis=0)`).

Comment: How can I procede, when I have multiple columns with same max value?

Comment: @Rockbar Please ask a new question and make a [reproducible pandas example](/q/20109391/4518341) including desired output, or at least an idea if you're not sure what would work best.

Answer (score 56):

And if you want to produce a column containing the name of the column with the maximum value but considering only a subset of columns then you use a variation of @ajcr's answer:

```
df['Max'] = df[['Communications','Business']].idxmax(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 14):

You could `apply` on dataframe and get `argmax()` of each row via `axis=1`

```
In [144]: df.apply(lambda x: x.argmax(), axis=1)
Out[144]:
0    Communications
1          Business
2    Communications
3    Communications
4          Business
dtype: object
```

---

Here's a benchmark to compare how slow `apply` method is to `idxmax()` for `len(df) ~ 20K`

```
In [146]: %timeit df.apply(lambda x: x.argmax(), axis=1)
1 loops, best of 3: 479 ms per loop

In [147]: %timeit df.idxmax(axis=1)
10 loops, best of 3: 47.3 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 6):

Another solution is to flag the position of the maximum values of each row and get the corresponding column names. In particular, this solution works well if multiple columns contain the maximum value for some rows and you want to return **all column names with the maximum value** for each row:<sup>1</sup>

[image: case1]

Code:

```py
# look for the max values in each row
mxs = df.eq(df.max(axis=1), axis=0)
# join the column names of the max values of each row into a single string
df['Max'] = mxs.dot(mxs.columns + ', ').str.rstrip(', ')
```

---

A slight variation: If you want to **pick one column randomly** when multiple columns contain the maximum value:
[image: case2]

Code:

```py
mxs = df.eq(df.max(axis=1), axis=0)
df['Max'] = mxs.where(mxs).stack().groupby(level=0).sample(n=1).index.get_level_values(1)
```

---

You can also do this for specific columns by selecting the columns:

```py
# for column names of max value of each row
cols = ['Communications', 'Search', 'Business']
mxs = df[cols].eq(df[cols].max(axis=1), axis=0)
df['max among cols'] = mxs.dot(mxs.columns + ', ').str.rstrip(', ')
```

---

<sup>1: `idxmax(1)` returns only the first column name with the max value if the max value is the same for multiple columns, which may not be desirable depending on the use case. This solution generalizes `idxmax(1)`; in particular, if the max values are unique in each row, it matches the `idxmax(1)` solution.</sup>

Comment: that's a very neat solution, thank you! How would I introduce (1) either random tie breaks (pick one column randomly when 2 or more columns contain the maximum value) OR (2) according to the maximum value in another range of columns, e.g. `['Comm..1', 'Sea..1', 'Busi..1']`, and ties broken according to the maximum of `['Comm..2', 'Sea..2', 'Busi..2']` (i.e. if `Comm..1` and `Sea..1` contain the max value between `['Comm..1', 'Sea..1', 'Busi..1']` in a row, check whether `Comm..2` or `Sea..2` contain a higher value in that row.

Comment: @Ivo I added a solution for case (1). Case (2) requires a drastically different solution imo, so you might want to ask a new question for it. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy argmax is blazing fast. I've tested in a dataframe with 3,744,965 rows and it takes 103ms.

```
%timeit df.idxmax(axis=1)
7.67 s ± 28.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit df.columns[df.to_numpy().argmax(axis=1)]
103 ms ± 355 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```