# For each row in data.table, find column name where value == X

Tags: r

I have a datatable formatted as follows:

`Name                 X1234 X5555 X3000 X5000 X7500 X8745 X9451 X8338 X8377
      Object 1         0+    0+    1+    0+    0+    0+    0+    0+    0+
      Object 2         1+    0+    0+    0+    0+    0+    0+    0+    0+
      Object 3         0+    0+    0+    0+    1+    0+    0+    0+    0+`

My datatable is filled with a couple of hundred rows; let's say Objects 1 to 100. All structured as followed. Each row, and thus Object, contains hundred+ columns. In one of these columns (which names are dynamic, but always start with **X**) I'm looking for the value **1+**. The next step i want to acccomplish is adding an extra column, let's name it **Number**, and fill it with the column name where the value of the row == **1+**.

So, my desired result would be:

`Name                 X1234 X5555 X3000 X5000 X7500 X8745 X9451 X8338  Number
      Object 1         0+    0+    1+    0+    0+    0+    0+    0+    X3000 
      Object 2         1+    0+    0+    0+    0+    0+    0+    0+    X1234 
      Object 3         0+    0+    0+    0+    1+    0+    0+    0+    X7500`

In R, what would be the best way to accomplish this? I have looked up and experimented with the functions like apply, which etc, but unfortunally haven't found a working solution yet.

I'm fairly new to developing scripts in R so my apologies if my question isn't clear or simple to answer.

Similar case in Python: 
[Find the column name which has the maximum value for each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29919306/find-the-column-name-which-has-the-maximum-value-for-each-row)

Comment: What if there are multiple columns with values +1 in the same row?

Comment: For each row there is only one column where the value is 1+.

Comment: Related: [For each row return the column name of the largest value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735859/for-each-row-return-the-column-name-of-the-largest-value). Just use a _condition_ in `max.col` (i.e `d == "1+"`), instead of the raw data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use apply and which:

```
df <- data.frame( x1 = c(0, 0, 1), x2 = c(1, 0 , 0), x3 = c(0, 1 , 0) )
idx <- apply( df, 1, function(row) which( row == 1 ) )
cbind( df, Number = colnames( df[ , idx] ) )

  x1 x2 x3 Number
1  0  1  0     x2
2  0  0  1     x3
3  1  0  0     x1
```

Answer (score 2):

An approach with `which`:

```
dat$Number <- names(dat)[which(dat == "1+", arr.ind = TRUE)[ , 2]]
# [1] "X1234" "X3000" "X7500"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `max.col` to find the column index of logical matrix (`df1[-1]=="1+"`).  Add 1 to it because we used only from 2nd column.  Then, with `names(df1)` get the corresponding names

```
df1$Number <- names(df1)[max.col(df1[-1]=="1+")+1]
df1$Number
#[1] "X3000" "X1234" "X7500"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `col` function to return the proper variable name index like this:

```
names(mat)[col(mat)[which(mat == "1+")]]
[1] "X1234" "X3000" "X7500"
```