# the biggest value in the row from the dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where the first column is time and other columns describe some characteristics. I would like to modify it so that for every time moment it prints the name of the column which is the biggest for that row:

```
 time  a  b  c  d
 0     4  8  3  7
 1     3  7  1  8
 2     1  0  9  2

 time  
 0     b
 1     d
 2     c
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the column name which has the maximum value for each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29919306/find-the-column-name-which-has-the-maximum-value-for-each-row)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `df.idxmax()`:

```
df.idxmax(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fun way

```
df.eq(df.max(1),0).dot(df.columns)
Out[105]: 
0    b
1    d
2    c
dtype: object
```