# Find the column name which has the 2nd maximum value for each row (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Based on this post: [Find the column name which has the maximum value for each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29919306/find-the-column-name-which-has-the-maximum-value-for-each-row) it is clear how to get the column name with the max value of each row using `df.idxmax(axis=1)`.

The question is, how can I get the 2nd, 3rd and so on maximum value per row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [`numpy.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) for position and then reorder columns names by `indexing`:

```
np.random.seed(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5,5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E
0  8  8  3  7  7
1  0  4  2  5  2
2  2  2  1  0  8
3  4  0  9  6  2
4  4  1  5  3  4

arr = np.argsort(-df.values, axis=1)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.columns[arr], index=df.index)
print (df1)
   0  1  2  3  4
0  A  B  D  E  C
1  D  B  C  E  A
2  E  A  B  C  D
3  C  D  A  E  B
4  C  A  E  D  B
```

Verify:

```
#first column
print (df.idxmax(axis=1))
0    A
1    D
2    E
3    C
4    C
dtype: object

#last column
print (df.idxmin(axis=1))
0    C
1    A
2    D
3    B
4    B
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

While there is no method to find specific ranks within a row, you can rank elements in a pandas dataframe using the [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) method.

For example, for a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 4],[3, 1, 7], [10, 4, 2]], columns=['A','B','C'])

>>> print(df)
      A  B  C
  0   1  2  4
  1   3  1  7
  2  10  4  2
```

You can get the ranks of each row by doing:

```
 >>> df.rank(axis=1,method='dense', ascending=False)
        A    B    C
     0  3.0  2.0  1.0
     1  2.0  3.0  1.0
     2  1.0  2.0  3.0
```

By default, applying `rank` to dataframes and using `method='dense'` will result in float ranks. This can be easily fixed just by doing:

```
 >>> ranks = df.rank(axis=1,method='dense', ascending=False).astype(int)
 >>> ranks
        A  B  C
     0  3  2  1
     1  2  3  1
     2  1  2  3
```

Finding the indices is a little trickier in `pandas`, but it can be resumed to apply a filter on a condition (i.e. `ranks==2`):

```
>>> ranks.where(ranks==2)
      A    B   C
   0  NaN  2.0 NaN
   1  2.0  NaN NaN
   2  NaN  2.0 NaN
```

Applying `where` will return only the elements matching the condition and the rest set to `NaN`. We can retrieve the columns and row indices by doing:

```
>>> ranks.where(ranks==2).notnull().values.nonzero()
    (array([0, 1, 2]), array([1, 0, 1]))
```

And for retrieving the column index or position within a row, **which is the answer to your question**:

```
>>> ranks.where(ranks==2).notnull().values.nonzero()[0]
    array([1, 0, 1])
```

For the **third** element you just need to change the condition in `where` to `ranks.where(ranks==3)` and so on for other ranks.