# Read column number of the non zero element of each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, feature-extraction

I have a dataframe, where every row has one non zero value only. I want to read the column number of this non zero value and put it in a new column. 
this is the dataframe

```
  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0 ...   0.0  0.0  0.0   
  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0 ...   0.0  0.0  0.0   
  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0 ...   0.0  0.0  0.0   
  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0 ...   0.0  0.0  0.0   
  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0 ...   0.0  0.0  0.0
```

The size of df is 30029x51. The column created should be

```
  2  
  2
  4 
  2
  2
```

Any idea on doing this using pandas

Comment: `(df == 1).idxmax(axis=1)` - [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29919306/find-the-column-name-which-has-the-maximum-value-for-each-row/29919489)'s a duplicate. `df.idxmax(axis=1)` also works if you only have zeros and ones.

Comment: Thank You , this is exactly what I am looking for