# How to get column name that has max value in a specific row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to get the column name that has max value for specific row.

```
    a   b   c
0   2   2   1
1   1   5   5
2   1   1   5
3   1   1   3
4   5   4   1
5   5   2   5
```

I expect to get column c when I search in index=2 and to get column a when I search by index=4.

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29919306/find-the-column-name-which-has-the-maximum-value-for-each-row) but it doesn't work.
In my real df, when I checked using df.info() , it shows me that Dtype is object not numeric.

Comment: Please change your sample data frame address your real question

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by converting the Dtype from object to **float**

[Find the column name which has the maximum value for each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29919306/find-the-column-name-which-has-the-maximum-value-for-each-row)

then I applied

[Find the column name which has the maximum value for each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29919306/find-the-column-name-which-has-the-maximum-value-for-each-row)

Answer (score 0):

You wrote that *dtype* is *object*, but on the other hand, your data
sample contains **only** integers and I assume that it is a representative
sample.

So the first step is to change *dtype* to *int*:

```
df = df.astype(int)
```

Then use the following function:

```
def maxColName(df, ind):
    return df.loc[ind].idxmax()
```

Or you can drop *df* parameter and use this name as a global variable:

```
def maxColName(ind):
    return df.loc[ind].idxmax()
```