# How to return the column title wherein the row contains the greatest value in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I working on a Python project that has a DataFrame like this:

```
data = {'AAA':  [3, 8, 2, 1],
        'BBB':  [5, 4, 7, 2],
        'CCC':  [2, 5, 6, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

which leads to:

|  | AAA | BBB | CCC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 | 5 | 2 |
| 1 | 8 | 4 | 5 |
| 2 | 2 | 7 | 6 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 4 |

And the task consists of generating the following DataFrame:

|  | AAA | BBB | CCC | Role |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 | 5 | 2 | BBB |
| 1 | 8 | 4 | 5 | AAA |
| 2 | 2 | 7 | 6 | BBB |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 4 | CCC |

Where "Role" column elements are the column headers that have the highest value in the row in which it is located.

Could you please help me by suggesting a code that solves this task?

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29919306/8508004).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `idxmax` method on axis:

```
df['Role'] = df.idxmax(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   AAA  BBB  CCC  Role
0    3    5    2  BBB
1    8    4    5  AAA
2    2    7    6  BBB
3    1    2    4  CCC
```