# iterate through dataframe and keep max value of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| datetime | hr | rmssd | neutral | happy | sad | angry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2012-09-18 13:17:00 | 61.0 | 0.061420 | 0.884570 | 0.076952 | 0.001144 | 0.017392 |
| 2012-09-18 13:18:00 | 64.0 | 0.049663 | 0.931965 | 0.031468 | 0.000371 | 0.023774 |

What I want is to be able to create a new column that on each row assigns the name of the column which holds the biggest value: ie: in the first column there would be the emotion column stating 'neutral'.
I tried iterating through each row like that:

```
for i in range(0,len(df3)):
    df3['emotion']=df3[['neutral','happy','sad','angry']].max()
```

but my resulting dataframe had an extra column named 'emotion' filled with NaN values. Note that I've deleted all of the NaN values from my df.

I also tried using iloc:

```
for i in range(0,len(df3)):
    df3['emotion']=df3.iloc[3:][i].max()
```

but zero luck there as well. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work without the `for-loop`. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29919489/6934388) -> duplicate?

```py
df3['emotion'] = df3[['neutral','happy','sad','angry']].idxmax(axis=1)
```

Comment: agreed this is a dupe - but good answer & find :)